# How to prevent auto opening of url on any browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, url

Is there a way in windows 10 , window firewall or any third-party program that can detect and block urls/links before it decide to open any browser . Here my issue, I was using a free vpn program call Psiphon and everytime I connect to a proxy it will open a link on my default browser. Im sure it happens to everyone who used Windows , for example whenever they uninstall a software succesfully , a website suddenly open up on their browser. The only crappy solution that I found is to use the Tab Close Gold extension , it still open the link but it auto close it in about 1 second then the it show the nearest tab. Just discover an old outdated solution , Browser Select , it presumably prompt you to choose which browser to open the url. is there anything similar usable now?

Comment: You can certainly block the website on your hosts file, but you'd still have to manually close the browser window. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: You COULD try to remove HTTP/S Win protocol app. GUI doesn't let you do this: Settings, Apps, Default Apps, ...apps by protocol. So you COULD try deleting some registry keys. NO IDEA what will happen & clearly Windows doesn't want this done. This won't stop app from opening web browser directly only those who respect users default browser. `(Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice' -Name ProgId).ProgID` `(Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice' -Name ProgId).ProgID`

Comment: "The only crappy solution that I found is to use the Tab Close Gold extension" :')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yup my theory is correct , all I need is no official browser (IE disabled/removed) installed and a portable unofficial browser . Windows might not be happy with you not having Edge installed , but Im sure theres a hack out there that can remedy that . I myself using a superlite Windows 10 version with no update capabilities , so I dont have to worry about Edge keeps coming back . Opening links or html files will be a problem and some regular browser functionality will not work but I can live with that :) .

Comment: This is a comment because it doesn't explain HOW to resolve the question that was asked, it just says the problem was solved.

Comment: It pretty much explain itself , atleast thats what I thought . I uninstalled/disabled all of my browser , and use a portable browser like ungoogled chromium that window cant detect. No browser detected , no links will be open. Its a weird solution but thats the only solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in a comment Windows doesn't seem to let you remove/set-none the default browser or HTTP/S protocol so what you're asking for Windows wasn't designed to do. All of these suggestions are just that, suggestions as I haven't tested them nor do I know if they will cause some issue so use at your own will.
**Option 1: Group Policy Default App Associations**

1. In admin powershell/command-prompt run this command: `Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:"c:\AppAssociations.xml"`
2. Open AppAssociations.xml in Notepad, delete all lines that start with '*Association Identifier*' except the ones that say `Identifier="http"` (or `Identifier="https"`)
3. Change ProgID & ApplicationName to just end in quotes. So your file should look like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <DefaultAssociations>
     <Association Identifier="http" ProgId="" ApplicationName="" />
     <Association Identifier="https" ProgId="" ApplicationName="" />
   </DefaultAssociations>
   ```
4. Open `gpedit.msc` as admin
5. Navigate to this setting: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\File Explorer\Set a default associations configuration file. Enable it & give it the path to the file we tweaked above.
6. Reboot (or sign out?) then cross your fingers. It may just ignore your config file as corrupt. The setting ALSO seems to imply it may only work for domain-joined PC's.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/set-the-default-browser-using-group-policy

**Option 2: Tweak registry to remove HTTP/S Protocol app association**
[Reference my comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1716251/how-to-prevent-auto-opening-of-url-on-any-browser#comment2651695_1716251)

**Option 3: Use Group Policy Software Restriction Policy to block this POSSIBLY**
This is complicated, but if the app uses a certain executable (unlikely, but possible) that triggers this action you can block the EXE from running. Basically you have to use some sniffer program (ex: [sysinternals Process Explorer, Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-utilities)) to find whats being run then block it. I've done this successfully with a free antivirus (AV) pop-up alerts to buy the subscription/full-program, but in that case they have a unique EXE that handled that so I blocked that separate EXE & the AV continued functioning

Comment: I tried option 1 and 2 , didn't work , I gave up trying option 3 because it seems too complicated , I implore you replicate my issue , using this Psiphon app . With that said I think I found the solution , it still in theory as I havent test this out yet but hear me out ,  what if I uninstall every browser there is on my pc (I used an unofficial windows 10 , so no update that can install Edge) and use a portable chromium . Im 99% sure this app wouldnt detect a portable browser. Finally i can live in peace. Im happy knowing i can be creative sometime :) .

Comment: I wonder if you could set default browser to an app that isn't a browser; or for example install a browser, set it as default and then make the executable non-executable (eg remove permissions for your user, or replace the exe with an empty file)